# How can i change the href of <a> of a button when i change the language of the site?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Okay, so here is the thing, i made a site in which you can change it into two different languages (spanish an english) and i have a button that everytime you click on it, redirects you to a pdf file which its in spanish but what should happen its that when the text on the button changes to english the file also changes to the file in english

Here its the button

```
<div data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="800" class="text-center">
          <a href="assets/img/File1.pdf" class="btn-get-started scrollto">Ver CV</a>
            
          </div>
```

So the idea its that the href of the  changes its value for the second file (which would be in english), i tried with only Javascript and also with JQuery, what i expect its that whenever the site its on english when clicking the button they'll see the file in English and when the button would be in spanish they'll see the file in spanish

```
<div data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="800" class="text-center">
          <a href="assets/img/File2.pdf" class="btn-get-started scrollto">Ver CV</a>
            
          </div>
```

Comment: Please show your JavaScript attempt. It should be something like `document.querySelector(".btn-get-started").href="assets/img/File2.pdf";`

Comment: How do you change texts?  It would be similar, but instead of changing `.text("hello")` it would be `.attr("href", "file2.pdf")`

Comment: If you name your files the same but put them in language folders, you'll find it much easier to manage them, eg `"assets/en/intro.pdf"` / `"assets/es/intro.pdf"`  - then it's just a case of changing "assets/en" to "assets/es" and you don't even need to know the file name, eg `$("a").attr((i, a) => a.replace("/en/", "/es/"))`  This could be improved by storing a "default" path on the element so that you don't need to know the previous language.  `$("a").each((i, e) => $(e).attr("href", $(e).data("doc-path").replaceAll("/en/", "/es/")));`

Comment: I tried this, but didn't work

Comment: *I tried but didn't work* - both the above comment and provided answer will work if implemented correctly, given the limited html/details provided.   The next step is for you to provide a *complete* snippet that shows what you have tried.  See [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if I understand right... It's a basic JS solution.

Here's the **HTML**

```
<div data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="800" class="text-center">
<a id="cvButton" href="assets/img/File1.pdf" class="btn-get-started scrollto">Ver CV</a>
```

Here's the **JS**

```
let btn = document.querySelector('#cvButton');

function updateCV(language) {
    
    if (language === 'english') {
        btn.href = 'assets/img/File2.pdf'; // Update to English 
    } else {
        btn.href = 'assets/img/File1.pdf'; // Remains Spanish
    }
}


updateCV('english'); // <- This is the command-line that invokes this function.
```

Inject updateCV  inside the other button/function that request the language-change.

Comment: I tried but didn't work, now the only file that you can see everytime you click on the button it's the english file

Answer (score 0):

If by changing language the website is refreshed you could use a server-side  variable to define the link like i.e in PHP template:

```php
<a data-lang="en" href="assets/img/File<?= $lang ?>.pdf" class="btn-get-started scrollto">Ver CV</a>
```

Otherwise,
however you change the website's language (not clear from your question) you should also change

```html
<html lang="en">
```

into

```html
<html lang="es">
```

and given you have this HTML:

```html
<div data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="800" class="text-center">
  <a data-lang="en" href="assets/img/File1.pdf" class="btn-get-started scrollto">Ver CV</a>
  <a data-lang="es" href="assets/img/File2.pdf" class="btn-get-started scrollto">Ver CV</a>   
</div>
```

than it's all about CSS:

```css
html[lang="en"] [data-lang="es"], 
html[lang="es"] [data-lang="en"] {
   display: none;
}
```